# Calling a javascript method with arguments / values from code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way for me to call a javascript method from code-behind that takes two arguments/values? Please check the following code:

```
private void ddl_Eval_SelectedIndexChanged (Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    dtEval = new DataTable();
    dtEval = data.GetEvaluation2();
    DataView dvEval = dtEval.DefaultView;

    string xmlDoc = String.Empty;

    foreach (DataRowView drvEval in dvEval)
    {
        if (drvEval.Row["EvaluationID"].ToString() == ddl_Eval.SelectedValue.ToString())
        {
            xmlDoc = drvEval.Row["EvalAnswers"].ToString();
        }
    }

    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
    xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc);

    foreach (XElement child in xdoc.Root.Elements("Answer"))
    {
        //Response.Write(child.Attribute("item").Value + " " + child.Value + "<br />");

        //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PUT THE CODE SO I CAN SEND THE VALUE
        //OF THE ATTRIBUTE "item" AND THE VALUE OF THE child node itself.

    }

}
```

And here's the XML string:

```
<ANSWERS>
  <Answer item="ddl_3">A</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_8">A</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_13">Y</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_16">Y</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_19">Y</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_22">N</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_26">Y</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_30">N</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_34">Y</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_38">N</Answer>
  <Answer item="ddl_42">StarLight</Answer>
</ANSWERS>
```

And this is the page wherein I want javascript to change the selected values of the `select` controls. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/HB99v)

Is it possible? I want to send those two arguments/values so that javascript can change the selected values of the `<select>` controls I have on the page.

Answer (score 0):

changing a data list

```
ddl_eval.items.clear()

foreach (XElement child in xdoc.Root.Elements("Answer"))
    {
       ddl_eval.items.add(child.Value,child.Attribute("item").Value);
    }
```

---

You don't need JavaScript -- I would code it like this:

```
Response.write("<answers>")

foreach (XElement child in xdoc.Root.Elements("Answer"))
    {
       Response.Write(@"<answer item="""+child.Value+@""">"+child.Attribute("item").Value+"</answer>");
    }

Response.Write("</answers>");
```

Also, modern html style is to have all tags lower case (xml requires it.)

---

You should use `this.Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(key, script);`

It might look something like this:

```
 this.Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("some unique name",@"
<script language=""JavaScript"">
   alert(""Hi, I'm some client script!"");
</script>");
```

Comment: Where do I need to put this block of code? And how will I be able to call it inside the `foreach (XElement child in xdoc.Root.Elements("Answer"))` loop?

Comment: Please modify your question to show what the exact output you want.

Comment: @Hogan: thanks, I read your updated answer. Uhm, I don't want to write my result as Xml, what I want is for me to change the selected values on the Screenshot link I provided earlier, based on the values from the Xml.

Comment: I'm writing html.  Because of the xml standards html follows them -- don't use caps or fist letter caps in your html as you have in the example.  Now to your question -- you have an existing select list and you want to replace the contents of the select list with new values?

Comment: Yes, I want the select to be replaced by another value from its list based on the value I have from the xml string.

Comment: ok I gave an example of how to change a drop down list items -- seems standard to me -- not sure why you are asking about javascript.

Comment: ok, then loop over the items in the items collection till you find the one you need and set selected item to that item.

Comment: @Hogan: I'm sorry if I'm not communicating effectively. :( I don't want to clear the items in the select controls, I want one of the items/ListItems in the select control to be selected based on the values I have from the xml string. So say for example, <answer item="ddl_3">A</answer>. The value of item is ddl_3 and the value of the answer node is A. I need to pass ddl_3 and A to javascript so javascript can search the page for the control/key ddl_3 and change the currently selected value (in which all of them have select as default value) into A.

Comment: There is no passing to javascript.  This is server side code.  You can make the change to the controls in memory and then the page will render the way you want.  This is code behide in ASP.NET I think you are getting confused with how ASP.NET works and how AJAX works.  Remember when this code is running NOTHING exists on the clients machine.  Maybe you want to re-engineer this to use AJAX?

Comment: I see. Uhm, but I saw an article here [link](http://arun-ts.blogspot.com/2007/09/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript.html) and it says that we can create scripts from code-behind,. I'm sorry, I'm totally new to .NET and javascript. :(

Comment: Ah I see... how you design your site should not be based on one article... lets talk in chat (link at top of page) -- go to "tavern"

Comment: @Hogan: oh, I'm sorry. I don't have enough reputations yet to be able to use the chatroom. :( Anyway, thanks for the help. I will read about AJAX and see how I can revise my code using that.

Comment: ok now you do... I'm still in the tavern if you want to come in and ping me.

Comment: @Hogan: thanks for the reputations you gave me. :D I tried going to that chatroom but StackOverFlow is giving me this message: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: yes. :( I also tried logging out completely then logging-in again. wait. Let me try to close the entire browser and try to log-in again.

Comment: hhmm.. I'll try it later. Maybe after an hour. Well, I don't know if you would still be online after that, but it's worth the try.

Comment: @Rome I can't stay long but you should be able to chat now.